# Custom SetPasswordForm not changing password on submit

Tags: django

I'm making a website and one of the features is that when user forgets his password he can reset it.  We all know that templates provided by django aren't beautiful so I created my own. **and everything works but the password_reset_confirm** Just to be clear if i have my custom templates on every view (reset_password, password_reset_done and password_reset_complete) but I'm using django provided password_reset_confirm page works password is changed but when im using my template and form for this password stays the same *Thanks for your help and have a great day*
btw if some code in views is requied im working with function based views

**Forms.py**

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm, SetPasswordForm

class CustomPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    email   = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'registerForm','name':'email'}))

class NewPasswordResetForm(SetPasswordForm):
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': ('New Passwords and Confirm Passwords not matching'),
    }
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'registerForm','name':'new_password1','id':'id_new_password1'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'registerForm','name':'new_password2','id':'id_new_password2'})
```

**Urls.py**

```py
from .forms import CustomPasswordResetForm, NewPasswordResetForm

path('reset_password/', reset.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="resetPassword.html",form_class=CustomPasswordResetForm), name="reset_password"),
path('new_password_send/', reset.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name="resetPasswordDone.html",), name="password_reset_done"),
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', reset.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="resetPasswordNew.html", form_class=NewPasswordResetForm), name="password_reset_confirm"),
path('reset_password_complete/', reset.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name="resetPasswordComplete.html"), name="password_reset_complete"),
```

**HTML**

```html
<form method="POST" action="">
  {% csrf_token  %}
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form.password1  }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     {{ form.password2  }}
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btnSbtRegister">
      <span class="textSbtRegister">
           {% trans "Change Pass"  %}
      </span>
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of password1 and password2 it is expecting a new_password1 and a new_password2 field. Also why are you overriding a form just to add css? Look into [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/), It lets you modify how the widget looks from the template.